# Express dynamic routing using / and /:slug as different route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

so I'm in the process of refactoring my node/express application and I'm trying to separate my roots. Here's my issue:

I want an homepage and then a completely different page for extensions, that doesn't fall into other routes.

So for example, let's say I have 3 pages: Homepage, About, and then an user page where the URL is "mysite.com/username123".

Now I know (or at least believe) this can be accomplished by doing something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.params.slug) {
        var data = { 
            my: 'data'
        };
        res.render('index', data);
    } else {
        var userdata = { 
            my: 'data'
        };
        res.render('user', userdata);
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

But this isn't what I want to do; I would like to keep these in two different route files. So my app.js file would have something like:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var about = require('./routes/about');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/', users);
app.use('/about', about);
```

Where `/users` renders if there is a slug. This actually sort of works. If there is no `:slug`, the index file is loaded, otherwise the users file is loaded (which has the :slug in the route file, not shown here). But then `/about` is overwritten.

Now I supposed I could shove `/about` to the top of the list and that would work, but this seems extremely sloppy and the whole point of doing this is to properly structure my code.

How are situations like this supposed to be properly handled? Could someone please give me some help here?

Comment: It happens because `/about` is overridden by `/:slug`. In other words, express cannot tell if `about` is not meant to be a slug

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it's happening. I just need to know how I'm supposed to get around this issue happening, while keeping the `/:slug` in a separate file than the homepage at `/`

Comment: You need to add something to the routes of users.Ex:  `router.get('/users/:id'` `

Comment: But I don't have a /users/ page, nor do I want one. I would like the username to appear right after the domain.

Comment: Ian in that case you can use `/:folder` and do the routing via a check in `req.params.folder` with a `if/else`condition

Comment: Yes, but then how can I keep those in separate route files? I attempted to do... `app.get('/:user', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.param.user) {
    app.use('/', index);
  } else {
    app.use('/', user);
  }
});` but that does not work. It just sends me the error page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because `/about` is overridden by `/:slug`. In other words, express cannot tell if `about` is not meant to be a `slug`.

Solutions would be to either

1. Add a url param to let express differentiate the routes.

   `router.get('/users/:slug')`
2. Skip to next route

   ```
   router.get(':slug', function (req, res, next) {
      if (req.params.slug === 'about') {
         return next();
   }

     // get user data and render
     res.render('user', userdata);
   });
   ```

Attach the `/about` route below this.

Comment: Damn. Not the elegant solution I was hoping for but that's what I will go with for now. If nobody can come up with a cleaner solution (if one even exists) in the next 24 hours I will vote mark this as the solution. Thanks man, much appreciated.

Comment: Over the top of my head, that's the best i could come up with. Please post if you find a more `elegant` solution

Answer (score 4):

Just rearrange your routes in this order

```
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/:slug', users);
```

The static route will take priority over the dynamic route.